# How can I generate dynamic charts with MySQL data?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, graph, charts

This is not a question about the names of libraries for making graphs.

I have a project that needed a way to make graphs with data that comes from MySQL.

My question is: A library that provide a **good integration and flexibility with external data**, in this case MySQL data?

I need to calculate averages, make pie charts, change the data in real time, etc.

I would prefer a library that doesn't use JPEG images in final graphs. I would like something like 
http://raphaeljs.com/analytics.html (anyone know if there's MySQL integration for this library?).

I saw the Google Charts API but I don't like the idea of not having library control on my server, and I read that it has limitations.

Comment: "best" is really subjective. I considered flagging for closure, but could you update with what you want it to be the best at?

Comment: With "Fel" clarification in the comment to Col. Shrapnel below, I think the question is of the subjective type as per FAQ #2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would let jquery or dojo render the data in a graph therefore saving computing power on the server take a look at these links

http://dojotoolkit.org/grids-charts

http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/top-jquery-chart-libraries-interactive-charts/