# How to construct a Database for this kind of Organizational Chart

Tags: php, mysql

So I am planning to create a dynamic organizational chart, can anyone give me a hint on how can I design my database? Org chart is something like image on the link below. Sorry for my bad drawing skills.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pGPr.jpg

Comment: https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=php+mysql+organization+chart   see also  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406983/how-can-i-generate-dynamic-charts-with-mysql-data when you get your d/b defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a lot to go on, but this is how I would start

Seeing as it's possible to build a tree structure from a flat array containing parent-child relationships (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196157/create-array-tree-from-array-list)), I would create a table holding `[department][parent department]` and whatever else you wish to store on departments themselves. If it's in only 1 language you can stick the description in there, etc. `Department` is key, `Parent department` a foreign key on the same table.

If you want it to have positions and people too, I would create separate tables for all of those. One mapping positions to departments, and one mapping people to positions.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I will follow it and see for the result.